# How to export data from inside nested function and import those data from another module

Tags: javascript, node-modules, module.exports

**How can i export inside  function variables and import from another module this data  **

```js
   
//data.js    
function abc(){
let str  = "Turag"

function d(a){
let v = a.toUpperCase()
return v
}

const bcd = d(str)
return bcd

}
module.exports.captial = abc

//index.js

const getData = require('./data.js)
"user": getData.v
clg(user)
```

Comment: You're never calling the exported function: `getData.captial()`. And no, you can (should) never export data from inside a (nested) function call, you only should `return` values from the call.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the exported function, with name you exported like capital not v.

```js
   
//data.js    
function abc(){
let str  = "Turag"

function d(a){
let v = a.toUpperCase()
return v
}

const bcd = d(str)
return bcd

}
module.exports.captial = abc

//index.js

const getData = require('./data.js)
"user": getData.capital();
clg(user)
```